# How to get Marker Click event perfect when multiple markers are nearly attached

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working on google map api.
I have set markers on map using icon path values.

My problem is that , i am not getting perfect marker click.
 
when i click on red marker it displays another marker info window.
 
And then click on other marker then it displays another marker info window.

Here is my Example : http://jsfiddle.net/u758rqpa/100/

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(markerA[i][2], markerA[i][1]),
    map: map,
    icon: {
        path: pathValue,
        fillColor: markerA[i][6],
        fillOpacity: 1,
        strokeWeight: strokeWeight,
        scale: scalesize,
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(200, 200),
        rotation: rotation,
    }
});
```

This is wrong click.
 
so, please help me to find out perfect marker click.
 
Or what i have to do to achieve that perfect marker click.
Means when i click on red marker it should display red in infowindow, when click on green it should display green infowindow.

so, please give me any solution to get this.

Comment: Update your question to include the code where you're attaching infowindows to the markers and defining your event listener for the marker click.

Comment: looks like you need to define the clickable area, take a look at the [HTML area tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_area.asp)

Comment: What's the final purpose of these markers? Do you want to create a kind of pie-chart based on values or will the markers have a fixed shape and only a different rotation?

Comment: markers have fixed shape and only different rotation, that is purpose.

Comment: -ducan , my code is in jsfiddle. That link is at top.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the marker `shape` property.

> **google.maps.MarkerShape object specification**
>
> This object defines the clickable region of a marker image for browsers other than Internet Explorer.

Everything is explained in the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerShape.

Comment: can you add that shape property in my markers code ?, 
and can you show me it works or not ?